Python and audio stream mixing in Linux + Pipewire
I'm basically trying to recreate what Deej does but with no config needed a textfile on the computer.
what i would like instead, is my python code creating any number (depending on the device's number of potentiometers) of Pipewire audio sinks and outputs channels that act like a passthrough, only adjusting the level (depending on the position of the potentiometers) , so that we can wire them as we want easily in a GUI (like in Qpwgraph for example).
here is a poor edit i made to try to explain my idea better:
Qpwgraph edited to illustrate the idea
i got the microcontroler sending potentiometer values on update via serial, i got python getting those values and printing them, but i don't know how to create and manage audio streams in python. Any suggestions on how to do it? ( which api? how to use it ? ) thanks in advance ;)
